# Kotlin Multiplatform Library - Info.plist invalid MinimumOSVersion

Tags: ios, kotlin-multiplatform, xcframework

Given a Kotlin Multiplatform library project with an android and iOS target, the generated XCFramework does have an invalid Info.plist-File.

The iOS Application can't be uploaded for review because the value for the `MinimumOSVersion` is set to 12.
My iOS-Application on the other hand does have a TargetSDK-Version of 15.
Is there a way to change the value of the `MinimumOSVersion` inside the `Info.plist` of the created XC-Framework?

I am using the latest stable Android Studio Release and Kotlin 1.9.10 and gradle 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

The Frameworks/shared.framework/Info.plist that contains the problematic `MinimumOSVersion` is generated by Konan. To double-check that it is indeed wrong, you can run `vtool -show Frameworks/shared.framework/shared` to see the discrepancy.

Normally you'd change the `MinimumOSVersion` in this generated Info.plist by adding:

```
freeCompilerArgs += listOf("-Xoverride-konan-properties=minVersion.ios=15.0")
```

to your `binaries { framework {...} }` in build.gradle.kts (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-56676).

The problem is that in Kotlin 1.9.10 combined with Xcode > 15.0, the `minVersion.ios` is **ignored**, and **you need to set** `minVersionSinceXcode15.ios` instead (which was introduced in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-60758).

As a solution, update your build.gradle.kts to:

```
freeCompilerArgs += listOf("-Xoverride-konan-properties=minVersion.ios=15.0;minVersionSinceXcode15.ios=15.0")
```

and rebuild, and you should pass the validation. Kotlin 1.9.20 seems not to have the minVersionSinceXcode15 any more, so I guess you'll be fine with just minVersion.ios again, but I haven't upgraded / double-checked myself yet.